# PHP COI Rate Calc foreach, for and possible while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I'm trying to achieve the below process using PHP but I'm stumped, is anyone able to provide a hand?

```
Get table that contains years from database
    Loop through each row (year) using a foreach loop
        Use a for loop to divide year into months (12)
            Do a calculation on each month which can only be verified on month 12 of each year
            If verification is unsuccessful +/- a number and re-run the for loop for the current year
            Else carry on to the next year
```

Many thanks

Comment: So what part of it are you having difficulty with and what have you already done?

Comment: I think by writing it out I may have found the solution, I will post back with the outcome or if more help is required, many thanks